# get permission from facebook fan page that has age restriction

Tags: facebook-graph-api, user-permissions

I have an access token that accesses all public content on fan pages, but one particular fan page has an age restriction. I access the fan page through my account but when using my app to access the wall I do not receive any content back or error messages. 
How can I ask for permission to access its content or extend my permission for my application? I have written my code in VB.NET.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. Need to get a new access_token and include the parameter scope = read_stream with request for token. Then all content is then accessible. Seems weird way in that the parameter does not actually validate the age factor.